# Maximum size sparse matrix NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, max, sparse-matrix

I am working on a model which reflects the spread of innovations through a society of `N` individuals. I have an adjacency matrix `A` of size `NxN`, note that this adjacency matrix is sparse.

I want to do simulations for `NxN=10^7`. I first tried Matlab, but unfortunately Matlab cannot handle `NxN>10^4`.

Is it possible to use NumPy for my simulations?

Comment: Numpy and Matlab work on very similar C routines under the hood. If Matlab can't handle it, I seriously doubt numpy can. Please look at an alternative using big data tools. PySpark is a good please to start.

Comment: N*N = 10^14......... You probably need a different representation; how many individuals are there in your sparse matrix?

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525344/whats-the-maximum-size-of-a-numpy-array

Comment: Sorry I meant NxN = 10^7, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Scipy can handle NxN sparse matrices with N=10^7

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
N = 10e7
sparse.bsr_matrix((N, N))
```

Output:

```
<100000000x100000000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
```

Whether it is suitable for your simulations depends on a number of things that we don't know. You might need to use a different [sparse matrix class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#sparse-matrix-classes).

Comment: `scipy.sparse` store element indices as integers.  For smaller matrices it uses `np.int32` but can use `np.int64` if needed.  So that allows very large shapes.  But the number of nonzero elements is limited by memory.  Unless very sparse, calculations will be slow compared to dense arrays.