# Error converting SciPy sparse matrix to numpy array: "array is too big"

Tags: python, scipy, countvectorizer

When attempting to convert a sparse matrix to a numpy array (using the **toarray** function), I'm getting the following error:

*array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.*

The size (shape[0], shape[1]) of the SciPy matrix is 15,561, 22417.

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Sounds like the resulting array is/would be too large for the allocated memory on your machine. Can you process it in batches?

Comment: I tried to loop through the matrix, this did not work either. Do i need more RAM?

Comment: What is `shape[1]` of the sparse matrix?

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525344/whats-the-maximum-size-of-a-numpy-array) there are a few options for reducing memory size such as decreasing precision or increasing memory allocation. Maybe see if any of those solutions works for you, or see if there's another way to do what you need to do to your data

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser its 22417

Comment: Also, what is the `dtype` of your array?  (I.e. `arr.dtype`)

Comment: And what platform are you running this on?  Windows?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Running windows. As far as type, not sure how to check type of a scipy sparse matrix ...

Comment: Check the `dtype` attribute.

Comment: scipymatrix.dtype is "numpy.dtype" ...

Comment: That doesn't look right.  If the sparse matrix is called, say, `m`, what is the output of `print(m.dtype)`?

Comment: This is a common problem.  The whole point to using `scipy.sparse` is be able to create and use matrices that would be too large if dense.  Why do you need to convert the sparse matrix `toarray`?  Changing the `dtype` might reduce the dense size by a factor of 2 or 4.  Even if such an array fits you won't be able to do much without making a (temporary) copy or two (and hitting the memory error again).

Comment: @hpaulj I want to convert it to a Pandas dataframe

Comment: A sparse dataframe, or a massive one with mostly 0s?  What does this sparse matrix represent?

Comment: @hpaulj, it represents word counts. I think the issue is I'm converting the entire matrix into a dataframe then aggregating (word count sum). I should probably aggregate, then convert.